# For Flutter In-App-Purchase, how to check the purchase has been made each time app is restarted?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm testing my first Flutter In-App-Purchase app. Where should I store the purchased info after the purchase has been made so the app can check when it restarts each time? If I store locally on a device, then the info will be lost after user clearing user data. If I store it remotely on firebase or other server, then the device has to be online to use the paid features. Can't seem to find what's the best solution.

It seems that `_inAppPurchase.purchaseStream.listen` only emits data stream when a purchase or a "restore previous purchase" is made not every time app is restated. Also, uninstalling and reinstalling app in Play Store doesn't automatically restore a previous purchase so I have to provide a button for manually restore the purchase.

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I ended up using shared preference. However, if user uninstall the app, the shared preference will be gone so I added an option for "restore purchase".

Answer (score 1):

_inAppPurchase.purchaseStream.listen is correct.

If you check it every time you run the app, a lot of traffic is generated. So, after purchase, we store it locally. And if you uninstall and install the app, you need to use the processor that stores it locally again by restoring the purchase list.